# Multiple Emails in Laravel Render View

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

How can I send two emails to the same view in Laravel?

```
$tmp = View::make($template_path, [
    'name' => $user->name,
    'email' => ($user->email, $email), // TWO EMAIL
            'email' => [$user->email, $email], // OTHER WAY   
            'phone' => $user->phone,
            'message' => $request->input("f_message"),
            'list_name' => $request->input("f_list_name"),
            'url_reclaim' => $url_reclaim
        ])->render();
```

Is this correct? Best regards.

Comment: use the send way : `'emails' => [$user->email, $email],` in your view, your gonna recieve an array of emails

Comment: btw, why you're using the old syntax of Laravel `View::make` ??

Comment: i am using laravel 5.3, i am using that since other projects and well that work fine, i will update in laravel 5.5 laravel , thanks for the suggestion xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer:

```
'emails' => [$user->email, $email]
```